# Flash no enviá los mensajes con passport.js estrategia local

Tags: nodejs, autenticación, passport

soy principiante en Node js y estoy desarrollando un proyecto de autenticacion con passport. El problema que tengo es que cuando las credenciales de autenticacion son falsas, no recibo el mensaje de flash en el lado del cliente. Aclaro que tengo configurados los mensajes de flash en la autenticacion local de passport. A continuacion paso el codigo de la estrategia local, del endpoint, y de la configuracion del servidor.

````
    // estrategia local 
    passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy({ passReqToCallback: true }, async (req, username, password, done) => {
        console.log('Attempting local authentication for username:', username);
        try {
          const user = await User.findOne({ username: username }).exec();
          if (!user) {
            debug('User not found:', username);
            req.flash('error', 'Invalid user or password');
            return done(null, false);
          }
      
          const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
      
          if (!passwordMatch) {
            debug('Incorrect password for user:', username);
            req.flash('error', 'Invalid user or password');
            return done(null, false);
          }
      
          debug('User authenticated successfully:', username);
          return done(null, user);
        } catch (err) {
          console.error('Error user authentication local strategy', err);
          req.flash('error', 'An error occurred during authentication');
          return done(err, null);
        }
      }));
      
    // Endpoint 
    
    ```
    router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
      failureRedirect: '/',
      failureFlash: true
    }), (req, res) => {
      res.redirect('/userpage');
    });
````